# How do I save the value of a DIV ID to database PHP & MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I have this div section:

```
<div id="address"></div>
```

and it shows the FORMATTED ADDRESS of the longitude and latitude of a location on Google maps. I have a draggable marker that will point to any location in the map and it allows to SHOW the address name, longitude, and latitude. I was able to successfuly save the longitude and latitude to my database in MySQL using PHP. But I failed to saved the address.

I used these following of lines of code to save the long and lat.

```
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude" name= "longitude">
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" name= "latitude">
```

But when I do

```
<input type="hidden" id="address" placeholder="address" name= "address">
```

there's no value passed. but the

```
<div id="address"></div>
```

is able to show the address on the webpage. So that's why how will I send the value of the div id="address" to php and MySQL database? Is there any way? Like converting it or so?

AND also, in order to visualize I have this html right here, http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html

as you can see, it is able to SHOW the address name also with the long and lat. I was able to save the long and lat on my database but how will I save the address name in database??? You can save the file with the link I shared and check the code.

Comment: id `#address` must be unique... jQuery will take the first `#address` it encounters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create an asynchronous HTTP request or more popularly known as AJAX. If you're familiar with the jQuery framework: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

say, your "submit" button is referenced with "btnSubmit" as its ID:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
```

you'll have to attach a "click" event handler so we'll know when it's been clicked or submitted:

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    /*this is where you'll place your ajax call*/
});
```

and to make your ajax call, you'll do something like this:

```
/*get the inner html value of div with "address" as its ID*/
var long= "long=" + $('#longitude').val();
var lat = "lat=" + $('#latitude').val();   
var data = "address=" + $('#address').html()+'&'+long+'&'+lat;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "my_php_script.php",
    data: data
})
.done(function(data) {
    /*handle successful call here*/
})
.fail(function(data) {
    /*oops, something went wrong*/
})
.always(function(data) {
    /*no matter what, let's do this*/
});
```

We can either use GET or POST as the ajax type. While we've used GET, you will have to make sure that on your my_php_script.php, you will have to use the following to get the "address" value passed as data parameter:

```
$address = $_GET['address'];
$long = $_GET['long'];
$lat = $_GET['lat']
```

The my_php_script.php is where you'll obviously utilize the address and do stuffs you'd want like saving to database and all.

Make sure to include the latest jQuery library though and wrap the js scripts on dom load:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
    /*all jscript goes here*/
});
```

Comment: but in my php file, it says address is undefined even though i already did it also exists in the database as field

Comment: Are you referring to the my_php_script.php file as used in the example above? That should be the actual file that processes your request when you're clicking the "submit" button, it is not the same page where the <div id="address"></div> resides.

Comment: Ok cool, did you make sure you have this added before your ajax call: var data = "address=" + $('#address').html(); and if you do have firebug installed on  your browser, you may want to check if an "address" field is being passed as parameter to your version of my_php_script.php file.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I was able to save the address on the database, but because of that button, now I am unable to save my long & lat... I was able to save it with this code

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude" name= "longitude">
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" name= "latitude">

Comment: My submit button is originally <input type ="submit" value ="Submit" > without the ID... but when i applied your button <input type ="submit" value ="Submit" id="btnSubmit" > the long & lat was not saved on my db but the address did

Comment: ah great!, well you may want to include both the long and lat as parameters too on my_php_script.php, I'll update my answer for this.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in helping. I would like to show my complete code.... here it is... http://1drv.ms/1MnjoeM (download 1mb only) the way im sending my long and lat is different

Comment: Just updated with longitude and latitude added as new parameters for the script. You may want to update how you handle each on your my_php_script.php. Let us know how it goes. :)

Comment: You're very welcome @KylieJ, if you believe this helped you solve your queries and perhaps you think this is the right answer, you may want to upvote it so others may find it useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you the address within the div

If you are using jquery

```
alert($("#address").html())
```

and if you are using plain javascript

```
console.log(document.getElementById("address").innerText);
```

Comment: how will I then pass it to PHP? In order for it to be passed on $address = $_POST['address']...

Comment: This is actually what I'm trying to get in this example, http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html, it is able to show the address using javascript but how will I save it on the database? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="address">Berlin, street 99, Germany</div>
<input type="hidden" id="address-to-save" name="address-to-save" value="">
```

jQuery:

```
var address = $("#address").text();
$("#address-to-save").val(address);
```